# How to force redirect to HTTPS when application has no web.xml

Tags: java, spring, servlets, openshift

I'm developing a web application using Servlet 3.x and I do not have web.xml instead I use the configuration annotation. I want to restrict all traffic to my application thats deployed in Openshift to be HTTPS. I found this article on how to do it in Tomcat(Jboss EWS).

https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202398810-How-to-redirect-traffic-to-HTTPS-

However the last step involves me changing the web.xml which I do not have. When I tried to find alternatives I could find articles on Servlet security. Can someone help me with the translation for this code snippet below?

```
A sample security-constraint directive in repo/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml looks like:

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to map `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` using `@ServletSecurity` annotation. It will only apply to the the patterns defined in the `@WebServlet`.

You could define annotations like this:

```
@ServletSecurity(@HttpConstraint(transportGuarantee = 
TransportGuarantee.CONFIDENTIAL))
@WebServlet(”/SSLServlet”)
public class SSLProtected extends HttpServlet {
}
```

However it would only make SSL requirement for accessing `that servlet` (the /SSLServlet pattern), not whole application. You could define such annotations for all your servlets, but it's much more error prone than using `web.xml`. 
That's why it is still recommended to use `web.xml` instead of annotations to define security constraints.

Just add`web.xml` to WEB-INF folder in your application with the fragment you provided and you will be good. Any reasons why you cannot use `web.xml`?

Comment: I'm not using web.xml just to move towards the newer way of defining the webapp configuration. If there is no way to be able to achieve force redirect via configuration, I would rather add that snippet on web.xml. However is it possible to have web.xml conflict with the annotation configuration? Can you give me an example of how to have them both ?

Comment: @SuChikki Newer doesn't mean always better ;). There is really no conflict, `web.xml` takes precedence and overrides annotations. How to use them both - you can configure your web components via @WebServlet, @WebFilter, etc, but stick to the security configuration (eg. login config, security constraints) via web.xml. During deployment information from both sources is merged.